# prop("selected",true) not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, prop

Does anybody know why in Safari this is not working?

```
$('#my_dropdown')
                 .find('option')
                 .filter(function(index) { 
                    return $(this).text() === $('#country_of_residence').html();        
                 }).prop("selected", true);
```

Where as in Chrome and Firefox it does. 
The option does get selected (as there is an atrribute selected="selected" visible), but the dropdown is not updated. 
I am using Safari 7.0.4.

Comment: Maybe try putting a `.prop("selected", false)` immediately after the `.find("option")`?

Comment: interesting. that actually worked!